# Pass Android device into Docker container

Tags: android, docker, adb

I faced with problem. I really don't know how to share my Android device into Docker container.
I have an image with Appium and ADB installed, and I wanna use ADB from container.
Tried it on my Mac OS device and on my ubuntu 22.04 server.
Also I tried to do:

1. Up container with privileged and pass /dev/usb/bus:

```
docker run -d --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb --name adbd sorccu/adb
```

2. Exec adb in container - empty devices list
   I have no clue what I need to do with this problem.

P.S. also I tried on windows machine with wsl (with usbip protocol). I passed device into wsl, I can see it with lsusb, but no device in adb devices list

Comment: Adb consists of a servers and a client. I would run adb server outside of the container and the adb client inside. Adb server runs on TCP port 5037 so instead of USB I would forward TCP port 5037 inside the container and start `adb start-server` on the host.

Comment: @Robert thank you! It seems it is the best idea to me